# Ant error: unmappable character for encoding Cp1252

Tags: java, ant, compilation, compiler-errors, javac

I am getting the following error when i build my project via ant.

```
ResourceManagerJDBCRAHA.java:40: error: unmappable character for encoding Cp1252  

If a ConnectionManager of type “JDBCxE2|x80? is found, it instantiates the class
```

This part of the code is actually a comment in my java file as following

```
/* If a ConnectionManager of type “JDBC” is found, it instantiates the class */
```

When i add single quotes instead of double quotes for JDBC (see below) i do not get this error

```
/* If a ConnectionManager of type 'JDBC' is found, it instantiates the class */
```

Following are the questions that i have:-

1. Why is this happening?
2. What can i do to resolve this i.e. by keeping the double quotes

I have tried adding encoding attribute like below which fixes the problem but gives rise to issues elsewhere

```
<javac .....  encoding="UTF-8"> .... </javac> 
error: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8
```

I would prefer to stick to the default i.e. without adding encoding attribute.

Comment: Well what encoding do you believe your code *is* in? Basically, you need to tell that to the compiler. Don't just *assume* it's UTF-8 - although *making* it UTF-8 would be a good idea. And why would you want to have curly quotes in your comments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look carefully at that comment, you will see that there are actually two different kinds of double-quote characters there: (“) and (").  (I'm not entirely convinced that this matches your source code ... 'cos I haven't been able to de-mangle it.)

The simple answer is to use ASCII double-quote characters exclusively.

The more complicated answer is to make sure that you know what the character encoding of your files REALLY is, and then set that encoding in the `build.xml` file.

---

> I would prefer to stick to the default i.e. without adding encoding attribute.

That is the best answer, but it requires you stick exclusively to using characters in the default character-set in your source code.  Since you can never be entirely sure what the compilation platform's default character set will be ... stick to 7-bit ASCII, and this double-quote character: (").

Comment: To clarify: If you need to use characters outside of the 7-bit ASCII set in `String` or `char` literals, use unicode escapes, e.g. `\u201C` for `“`.

Comment: @Andreas - correct.  But a programmer certainly doesn't need to use "funky" quotes in comments!!!

Comment: Thanks @StephenC, i have edited the question and added quotes matching the source code. Unfortunately i haven't written this class and i don't really know why one would need "funky" quotes. But this class has been compiling fine with eclipse for years. May be i am a noob but i don't really understand why would this be a problem while using Ant

Comment: The problem is that Ant and Eclipse are telling the respective compilers to use different character sets, and in the Ant case it is not using the correct one.